# Send parameter value struts1 via <html:link>

Tags: java, struts-1, hidden-field

I tried to send value of id-property via link as

```
<html:link action="action?method=view&amp;newsID='<bean:write name="news" property="id"/>'">View</html:link>
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="newsID" value='<bean:write name="news" property="id"/>'/>
                <html:link
                    action="action?method=view&amp;newsID=${newsID}">
                View
                </html:link>
```

But nothing work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do yourself a favor, and use the JSTL:

```
<c:url var="theUrl" value="/action.do">
    <c:param name="method" value="view"/>
    <c:param name="newsID" value="${news.id}"/>
</c:url>
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(theUrl)}">View</a>
```

Comment: Can I do passed parameters as hidden?

Comment: No. A link always sends a GET request, and parameters of a GET are always in the query string.